# Making a table or expression based on previous values

Tags: recursion, difference-equations

I would like to illustrate rational expectations based on the following equation

```
p[[t+1]] == 1/(1 - ψ (β - 1)) m[[t+1]] - ψ (β - 1)/(1 - ψ (β - 1)) p[[t]]
```

by building a table or manipulating to make an algebraic form from t=1 to 10 while keeping p and m symbolic.

How could I go about it?

Comment: You've seen `RecurrenceTable[]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After @J.M., but note that you may have to define an initial value for `m[0]`:

```
FullSimplify@
  RecurrenceTable[{p[t + 1] == 
  1/(1 - ψ (β - 1)) m[t + 1] - ψ (β - 1)/(1 - ψ (β - 1)) p[t], 
   p[0] == 1}, p, {t, 1, 4}] // MatrixForm
```

$\frac{-\beta  \psi +m(1)+\psi }{-\beta  \psi +\psi +1}$

$\frac{(\beta -1)^2 \psi^2-(\beta -1) (m(1)+m(2)) \psi +m(2)}{((\beta -1) \psi -1)^2}$,

$\frac{(\beta -1)^3 \psi
   ^3-(\beta -1)^2 (m(1)+m(2)+m(3)) \psi ^2+(\beta -1) (m(2)+2 m(3)) \psi -m(3)}{((\beta
   -1) \psi -1)^3}$,

$\frac{(\beta -1)^4 \psi ^4-(\beta -1)^3 (m(1)+m(2)+m(3)+m(4)) \psi
   ^3+(\beta -1)^2 (m(2)+2 m(3)+3 m(4)) \psi ^2-(\beta -1) (m(3)+3 m(4)) \psi
   +m(4)}{(-\beta  \psi +\psi +1)^4}$

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to RecurrenceTable!

Comment: Consider 
$$
p_t=\frac{m_t}{\psi +1}+\frac{\psi  \left(e_t p_{t+1}\right)}{\psi +1}
$$

$$
e_t p_{t+1}=e_t \left(\frac{m_{t+1}}{\psi +1}+\frac{\psi  \left(e_t p_{t+2}\right)}{\psi +1}\right)=\frac{e_t m_{t+1}}{\psi +1}+\frac{e_t \left(\psi  \left(e_t p_{t+2}\right)\right)}{\psi +1}=\frac{e_t m_{t+2}}{\psi +1}+\frac{\psi  \left(e_t p_{t+2}\right)}{\psi +1}
$$

What I should get is 

$$
p_t=\frac{\psi  \left(\frac{e_t m_{t+2}}{\psi +1}+\frac{\psi  \left(e_t p_{t+2}\right)}{\psi +1}\right)}{\psi +1}+\frac{m_t}{\psi +1}
$$

I'd like to expand to n cycles